# How to write value based on combination of other values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, case

The example data looks like this:

[image]

**the goal is:**

If we have the same `ControlNo` and `ActionDate` (including time) 
and combination of `Action = 'Changed status'` and  `'Print Quote'` then `'Print Quote'`

If we have the same `ControlNo` and `ActionDate` (including time) 
and combination of `Action = 'Changed status'` and  `'Reason for quote'` then `'Changed Status'`

Example query:

```
declare @TempTable table (
    Name varchar(50), 
    ControlNo int, 
    PolicyNumber varchar(50), 
    Action varchar(max), 
    ActionDate datetime
)


insert into @TempTable values 
    ('Jim',54321, NULL, 'Changed status','2019-01-29 09:56:12.820' ),
    ('Jim',54321, NULL, 'Print Quote','2019-01-29 09:56:12.820' ),
    ('Brian',12345, NULL, 'Changed status','2019-02-15 11:18:07.356' ),
    ('Brian',12345, NULL, 'Reason for quote','2019-02-15 11:18:07.356') 

select * from @TempTable
```

Desirable result should look like this:
[image]

I tried to achieve that by:

```
select   
    name, 
    ControlNo, 
    PolicyNumber, 
    case 
        when  action in( 'Changed status','Print Quote') then 'Print Quote'
        when action in ('Changed status', 'Reason for quote') then 'Changed Status'
        else Action end as Action
from @TempTable
group by 
    name, 
    ControlNo, 
    PolicyNumber, 
    Action
```

But it does not give me correct result:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this without using a subquery, by using *conditional aggregation* to implement the logic:

```
SELECT
    Name, 
    ControlNo, 
    PolicyNumber,
    ActionDate,
    CASE 
        WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN Action = 'Changed status'  THEN 1 END) = 1 
        AND  MAX(CASE WHEN Action = 'Print Quote'     THEN 1 END) = 1
            THEN 'Print Quote'
        WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN Action = 'Changed status'   THEN 1 END) = 1 
        AND  MAX(CASE WHEN Action = 'Reason for quote' THEN 1 END) = 1
            THEN 'Changed Status'
        ELSE MAX(Action)
    END AS Action
FROM @TempTable
GROUP BY 
    Name, 
    ControlNo, 
    PolicyNumber, 
    ActionDate
```

NB: in my opinion the results make more sense with the `ActionDate` column included (since it is part of the non-aggregated columns).

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8941f6f27ae28541ba525f6f6926ffc2)** yields:

```
Name  | ControlNo | PolicyNumber | ActionDate          | Action        
:---- | --------: | :----------- | :------------------ | :-------------
Brian |     12345 | null         | 15/02/2019 11:18:07 | Changed Status
Jim   |     54321 | null         | 29/01/2019 09:56:12 | Print Quote
```

Comment: Yes, ActionDate have to be included. Sorry, I forgot to put it in my select statement

Answer (score 1):

Please note "IN" condition works as "OR".

The code which can help:

```
SELECT a.Name,a.ControlNo,a.PolicyNumber,a.Action,a.ActionDate
FROM (
    SELECT t.Name,t.ControlNo,t.PolicyNumber
        ,CASE 
            WHEN t2.Action = 'Print Quote' THEN 'Print Quote'
            WHEN t2.Action = 'Reason for quote' THEN 'Changed status'
        END AS [Action]
        ,t.ActionDate
    FROM @TempTable t
    LEFT JOIN @TempTable t2 ON t2.ControlNo = t.ControlNo AND t2.ActionDate = t.ActionDate AND t2.Action <> t.Action
    WHERE t.Action = 'Changed status'
) a
GROUP BY a.Name,a.ControlNo,a.PolicyNumber,a.Action,a.ActionDate
;
```